# Mounting cifs share in Ubuntu using NetBios name, not IP address

Tags: networking, ubuntu, mount, samba, netbios

I've got a pair of Ubuntu machines and a Windows PC. If I create a share on the Windows PC, either Ubuntu computer can mount it using `mount -t cifs -o username=me //computername/sharename /mnt/mountpoint`. If I create a share on either Ubuntu machine, the Windows computer can see it at //computername/sharename on the network and access it just fine.

However, if I create a share on one Ubuntu computer (either) and try to mount it on the other one, I get `mount error: could not resolve address for computername: Unknown error`. Using the IP instead of the netbios name gets it mounted just peachy.

Even more strange, `nmblookup computername` yields the IP address.

What do I need to do on the Ubuntu sharing- and mounting- computers in order to mount the share by netbios name instead of IP address? (Outside of making a bash script to retrieve the IP address from the netbios name every time, or setting static IPs).

Answer (score 1):

System-wide NBNS support is not a standard part of Ubuntu (or most other Linux systems). The reason `nmblookup` works is because it generates and and receives NBNS packets on its own, while all other tools (including `mount.cifs`) rely on the global "resolve hostname" function to pick the right protocol.

The hostname lookup module for NBNS is called `libnss_wins.so.2`, usually packaged either as *libnss-winbind* or just part of *smbclient*. Once installed, Debian and Ubuntu will automatically activate it, otherwise it needs to be added to the "hosts" line of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
- hosts:          files dns
+ hosts:          files dns wins
```

To work, the module needs *winbindd* to be running. (I think previously it used to work standalone, or just with *nmbd* running, but apparently not anymore.)

Test with:

- `getent ahosts ComputerName` for all active modules (those listed in *nsswitch.conf*),
- `getent -s wins ahosts ComputerName` for the *wins* module specifically (whether active or not).

Comment: Could you explain this a little more for me? I'm not sure what to do with the information you've given me so far. Simply adding those two lines to the nsswitch.conf files didn't do anything to the problem. Is there a way for me to check or activate winbindd? Or could I check to see if libnss_wins.so.2 is not functioning properly?

Comment: ...actually, why doesn't my global "resolve hostname" function work with Linux shares when it does with Windows ones?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a script to look up the IP address each time, this should work: `mount.cifs -o user=USER "//$(nmblookup COMPUTERNAME | head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 1)/SHAREPATH" /MOUNTPOINT`
, replacing the capitalized variables as needed.